# how to bind values to an object in order of insertion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have some inputs, and I want to get data in order of insertion, for example: 
 if I insert the value `bbb` then the value `aa` I want to get `bbb` befor `aa`
I search in the net and find that this order is ensured using `Map`but I don't know how to use it with `ng-model`.
thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
I'm using an object that store the value of the **inputs** and a customized **key** passed with value 
here is an [example](http://codepen.io/Has1/pen/aBLNyo?editors=1011), if you insert the values in input `3` then `2` then `1`, and click ok, in the console the output will be ordered in an alphabetic order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @czosel, javascript objects are not ordered, and are usually sorted by alphabetical order of the keys.  Therefore, your best solution is probably going to involve going beyond using the `ng-model` directive as is.

Here are two possibilities you could try out:

#### Solution 1

In every `<input />` place an `ng-blur` directive that will determine the input's order.  For instance:

**HTML**

`<input ng-blur="onBlur('model1')" ng-model="model1" />
<input ng-blur="onBlur('model2')" ng-model="model2" />`

**controller.js**

```
app.module('myModule').controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;

  $scope.onBlur = function(key){
    // check if anything was entered
    if($scope[key]){

      // make sure this is first time data was entered into this input
      if(!$scope[key].order)
        $scope[key].order = $scope.count++;
    }
  };
}]);
```

#### Solution 2

Store the values in an array.  Similar to the first solution, but instead of keeping count, you would forego the `ng-model` altogether and manually add the value to an array (after checking that it doesn't already exist, which gets a little tricky with an array).  Of course you also have to handle updates yourself, so the first method is definitely going to be simpler.  The [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library will probably be of much help if for some reason you decide to choose this approach.

Lots of luck!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Object properties have no guaranteed order, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Try using an array instead.

Comment: I have seen that question, but how can I use an array, taking into account that my keys are not integer

Answer (score 0):

You can Queue(First in First Out) to get data in the order of insertion. Trigger a function and store the values binded in ng-model into queue.

Ex: ng-model = data // here data will be bbb

```
var queue = [];
function bind(value){
queue.push(value); // value will be bbb       
}
```

if user enters aa then again bind function needs to be called to push the value inside queue
U can get the values in the order of insertion.